# Display title caption along with image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, caption

I have created this [slider](http://www.lifewelllived.co.uk/example/version1/index.html) using motiongallery.js (CMotion Image Gallery) from Dynamic Drive.

I'm trying to setup an alt or title text as a caption using jQuery Capty, however it doesn't show properly (see [here](http://www.lifewelllived.co.uk/example/version2/index.html)).

Does anyone have any hints or advice on how to make this work?

Comment: Looking at the code examples on the Capty plugin page and the code on your page they're completely different. Also you have multiple images with the same ID on that page. IDs are unique. Use a CLASS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class to your CSS file. That must fix the whole thing right up.

`.capty-wrapper{display:inline-block;}`

The problem is that `<a>` and `<img>` are inline elements.
Capty uses `<div>`s for its caption rendering which is a block element which messes up the layout of the gallery.

The above CSS makes the containing div of capty into an inline element.

Also consider Billy Moat's comment and use 
`$('.caption').capty();`
for adding captions to ur image lements as ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Thank you Samyam that worked perfectly. But do have one more question... Is it possible to make it work for iphone, I mean i know the slider is design for hover and mobile devices don't have have hover but can i make it to slide left or right by dragging on screen?

Comment: There are many touch enabled galleries you can check out. TouchGallery is a jquery plugin that i know of. But different libraries have varying feature sets. So search for one that suits your requirements.